# Is pipe the same as expr pipe?

Tags: pipe

I search man expr and found expression 1 | expression 2 to reutnr expression 1 if it is neither an empty string nor zero; otherwise, returns evaluation of expression 2 if it is not an empty string.

Isnt pipe suppose to pass expression 1 into expression 2?

Are these 2 pipes different?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are different.

Note `man expr` also states:

> Beware that many operators need to be escaped or quoted for shells.

The `|` used by `expr` is not a pipe and must be typed either within quotation marks or escaped as `\|` to prevent `bash` from treating it as one.